# What's the "proof" of having presented a project results in a conference?

Tags: conference, cv, presentation

I am a Physics master's student trying for PhD. During my summer internship I worked on a project in a research lab. During the work I found a a few inconsistencies with work done by the Post-Doc and I also redid the analysis with new data. Because of this I was included as second author in a presentation given by the Post-Doc in a conference (our common guide was the third author). I do not have any "proof" as such for this, except for the keynote presentation. How am I supposed to mention this in my CV? I mean, if it was an actual paper I can give a link to the paper, however the conference presentations do not have  any such things I think. Is there any official way to do this or should I just give my guide as a referee so that admission committee will contact the guide in case they need to verify this?

Because it was presented in a conference I am hoping it'll be published at some point in the future(we are still working on the project), but I have to apply for few institutes with next few months, and the project won't be completed by then.

Comment: I've always just done "Authors. *Title*. Conference. Date." for posters. This should be enough for them to verify it with the proceedings if they care that much.

Comment: This isn't quite relevant to your particular situation, but conferences will often give a "certificate of presentation" or something along those lines to people who present a talk or poster. This is usually used as "proof" for funding/grant sources who want to verify that you actually presented at the conference they funded you to travel to.

Comment: @ekl I've only ever used something like that as documentation for travel expense reimbursement, it would be weird to include or reference it in a CV (I think that's what you mean by it not being quite relevant, but wanted to make sure that's clear to OP).

Comment: @BryanKrause yes that's what I meant, thanks for making it explicit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of us have some items on our CVs that have no supporting proof.  I recommend checking what can be found on the internet to be sure the information on your CV matches that information.  If there is a big mismatch between your memory and the written record, you should ask for advice on that. However, if there is no listing at all, go ahead and put down the facts as you know them, before you forget them.

The real issues is whether in your field, people generally list presentations by collaborators.  If not, perhaps it is normal to list on-going projects and collaborations.  Or, if you have a short CV, you can buck convention a bit and list what you think is relevant.  You can remove it later on.

The confirmation of many facts on your CV will come from letters of recommendation.  If your "common guide" writes in a letter it will likely mention the collaboration.  Also, most letter writers will ask for a recent CV, and will tell you if you have anything that looks misleading.

By the way, you probably should not list a URL to any paper you get published.  Stick with the formal bibliographic conventions, and perhaps list at DOI.  If you have something like a code repository, you should then put in a URL.

On more thought.  The fact that your guide can validate this work is just one reason to pick that person as a letter writer (referee).  From what you wrote that seems like a good choice, but you need to think about all sorts of facts. (There are Lots of questions on that sort of thing on this site.)  If you have other letter writers who can expound on your research accomplishments and abilities, you might not select this person as a letter writer.  It still could be fine to list this item on a CV.

Comment: Thanks. Until other answers mentioned it I didn't know about the thing called Conference proceeding. Indeed the presentation is listed as "PoS(.....)". But only the first author's name (one who presented it) is listed, as you rightly guessed. I presume it's alright to mention this in my CV.

Comment: @Indigo1729 Since then there is a discrepancy between the proceedings and how you and the presenter considered this, you should get advice from someone close on how might can list this.

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of any published proceedings that names presenters and such, you could always ask the conference *Program Chair* (or equivalent) for a letter stating that you gave the presentation. If your talk was invited, the invitation should be enough, actually.

Long term, though, think about the issue as you submit to various venues how you will keep appropriate records.

Comment: Conferences usually give each presenter a certificate of attendance/presentation. You might ask the post-doc for a copy. Otherwise, I think the post-doc should contact the conference chair for the letter as conferences usually provide such certificates or letter only to the attendees.

Comment: @Buffy Thanks. I didn't know about the thing called Conference proceeding. Indeed the presentation is listed as "PoS(.....)". But only the first author's name (one who presented it) is listed. I presume it's alright to mention this in my CV .